# Smart router / proxy to containers

Tags: web, docker, proxy, routes

I have some simple project that based on 2 docker containers. 
Containers are Apache servers - with static HTML files (without PHP).

- Container 1: Public content.
- Container 2: Private content - for registered users only.

The idea is that users enter to some link, lets say:
`http://domain.com/HASH_ID`

Then I need to route them to the right container. Users have tokens in their
`localstorage`(or `cookies`) - so that's way I can detect where I need to route 
the user.

My problem is that I can't understand how to develop that router.

The issue is that I can't change to URL - so I can't create sub domains, URL 
level or something like this... I need to allow to users copy urls and sends to 
each other.

Please take a look to the attachment image bellow, maybe it will help to 
understand the arch.
[image]

Comment: I found that there is a tool - called "Bouncy" - https://github.com/substack/bouncy. Maybe that's can help me? Any alternatives?